# Can make expand several macros in the external text file for me?

Tags: macros, makefile

I've got a rather big and verbose section of line-based configuration file. I'd like to use this section as template (assuming I going to preconfigure this section, test it and then replace actual values with `$(make)` `$(macros)`), substituting the key parameters (very few of them, really) effectively "cloning" this "template" with few customized parameters to the working config file. Can `make` do the work for me in the described case?

<sub>Please bear with me, I'm truly a `make` layman and even not sure if it is right tool in this case.</sub>

---

### An example

I'm preconfiguring and testing something like:

```
<section0>
contains a lot of settings
which were tested and should 
be exactly the same in every copy 
except marked with trailing0 
</section0>
```

I'm wondering that if convert tokens marked with trailing zero above to macros:

```
<$(section)>
contains a lot of settings
which were tested and should 
be exactly the same in every copy 
except marked with $(trailing) 
</$(section)>
```

... wondering that I can utilize `make` to produce clones of premade configuration slightly customized with my data in place of macros:

```
<section42>
contains a lot of settings
which were tested and should 
be exactly the same in every copy 
except marked with trailing42
</section42>

<foo>
contains a lot of settings
which were tested and should 
be exactly the same in every copy 
except marked with bar
</foo>
```

Assuming `"section42"`, `"foo"` and `"trailing42"`, `"bar"` are substitutes for `$(section)`, `$(trailing)` macros respectively.

Comment: Can you provide a simple illustration just to help understand what you are speaking about? If you want a file consisting of `key=value` lines to change the behavior of your `make`, it's what the [include](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html) statement is for.

Comment: @AlexCohn, please check it out, I've added an example, hope it became little more clear. But still unsure it make is an applicable tool for that.

Comment: `<foo> … except marked with bar`? How would the computer know? And what do you mean by _marked with bar_?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`m4`](http://mbreen.com/m4.html#toc5) preprocessor in your makefiles to do exactly that: expand macros in template files:

> M4 can be called a “template language”, a “macro language” or a “preprocessor language”. The name “m4” also refers to the program which processes texts in this language: this “preprocessor” or “macro processor” takes as input an m4 template and sends this to the output, after acting on any embedded directives, called macros.

Create a file named `section.m4`:

```
$ cat section.m4 
<section0>
contains a lot of settings
which were tested and should
be exactly the same in every copy
except marked with trailing0
</section0>
```

And have a rule in your makefile to expand macros in that template to produce `section.cfg`:

```
section.cfg : section.m4
    m4 -Dsection0=foo -Dtrailing0=bar $< >$@
```